# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException

Tags: jsf, tomcat, glassfish

When I installed a new instance of the Tomcat 7 with a default .jsf program the error above isn't shown. When I did basic changes in the program through of the Netbeans 7.4, I got this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException.

My tests showed me that this error is related with code. But, I expected a better error message. I'm running Tomcat 7.

I tried to work around the situation using Glassfish 4, but I stuck with error: SEC5054: Certificate has expired.

I'm running on W32 and I'm thinking to change to Debian64. Probably the issues are understandable.

What do you think about?

Comment: There are some references to similar problem over the web. E.g.: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2678. Also in comments here https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_7_and_netbeans. It was resolved there by using glassfish 4 build 72 instead of 74.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. related to the issue com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException I changed encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 just in one file (index.xhtml), but I had others two: web.xml and projectname.xml to change too.

I'll try to solve other issue: SEC5054: Certificate has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You might have different java versions 1.6/1.7 in NetBeans/Glassfish